# How come Leonardo just took my codex page?

Tags: assassins-creed-2

I just acquired a codex page in a guarded house in Venice. I went to Leonardo to have it decoded, and he said "Ah, this one is easy!". Next second I'm back on the street where a pickpocket is running away right in front of me. Funny thing was, once I killed the pickpocket I didn't get any money. I'm getting the feeling this was some kind of "new gadget" test or something that I didn't get.

I've been over every codex page in the database and I can't find one describing a piece of technology I don't already have. Also the Leonardo icon has disappeared from the map, and my inventory says I have 8 decoded and 0 encoded codex entries.

What the hell is going on?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Codex is not only a description of new technologies and enhancements for your hidden blade, but also pieces of a larger mystery. Ezio must figure this mystery out, but the pages of the Codex are encoded. Leonardo, being a genius, can decode these codex pages with ease.

In Monteriggioni, there's a room where Ezio inserts the decoded codex pages. You can see the contents that Leonardo managed to decode there.

Not every codex page describes a new technology - some are there just to advance the plot. For every 4 codex pages that Leonardo decodes, you gain one extra square of health.

The Leonardo icon will appear again only when you have new pages for him to decode.

The cutscene where Leonardo says "Ah, this looks easy" repeats for every codex page that is not an enhancement to your equipment or that is not vital to the plot.

Note that you need to find and decode all codex pages to finish the game.

I feel that the pickpocket issue is unrelated to the codex entries.

Comment: But I still have no idea what the codex page contains. Also it felt like the pickpocket interfered with the cut scene, if that's at all possible. It doesn't really make sense to me that Leonardo goes "Ah, this one is easy" and I'm back on the street the next instant. I should at least be informed what the codex page contained. If it turns out you're right, in which case I'll be quite disappointed in the game, I'll of course mark this as the correct answer. Could someone who's played through the game perhaps confirm or refute that the cut scene only contained 5 words and lasted for 4 seconds?

Comment: @Codemonkey Sorry by my previous, rushed answer. I was kinda busy at work. I made some edits clarifying the working of the codex pages. I don't recall if the room where the codex pages are stored appears ever since you collect your first (Mario shows the room to Ezio), but whenever you go there you can deposit your decoded codex pages and read its contents. There's also another secret contained in these pages, but you will find out later.

Answer (score 0):

You know actually it's just apart of the game that he takes the codex. It goes on the wall in the villa and you get florins and a health square.